# Python subprocess within windows service (no piping)

Tags: python, windows, service, subprocess, popen

I have put together a simple python web server using CherryPy.  It serves as a printer for a web application I've made so that the web app can POST details to be printed to localhost.  The web app itself is served from a remote machine.  The local python server builds a postscript file and then prints it out using a Ghostscript subprocess.

It works perfectly when I start the python script from a command line, but for production I would like it to run as a windows service.  Thus, I have made it into one, but my subprocess.Popen didn't make the transition very well.  It get a 200 response back, the postscript file is generated correctly, but Ghostscript doesn't do ANYTHING.

I have searched for solutions to this problem, but I have only found solutions for when someone wants to mess with stdin/stdout/stderr.  In my case, I am not trying to and thus can't find a fix.  Here are a few of the links I've read through.

http://bugs.python.org/issue1238747

http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/851608-using-subprocess-popen-windows-service

Here is the code:

```
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32api
import win32con
import win32event
import win32evtlogutil
import os, os.path, sys, string
import cherrypy
import shutil
import subprocess

def CORS():
    cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'

conf = {
    '/': {
        'tools.sessions.on': True,
        'tools.CORS.on' : True,
        'tools.staticdir.root': os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()),
        'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
        'tools.response_headers.on': True,
        'tools.response_headers.headers': [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')]
    }
}

class WebServer(object):
    exposed = True

    def POST(self,TKTcategory,TKTitem,TKTsize,TKTprice,TKTbarcode):
        shutil.copyfile(r"C:\DOHR\ticket_template.ps",r"C:\DOHR\ticket.ps")
        with open(r"C:\DOHR\ticket.ps", "a") as myfile:
            myfile.write("15 15 moveto (" + TKTbarcode + ") (includecheck includetext height=0.3)\n")
            myfile.write("/code128 /uk.co.terryburton.bwipp findresource exec\n")
            myfile.write("/Helvetica findfont 9 scalefont setfont\n")
            myfile.write("/ticket_text (" + TKTcategory + ":" + TKTitem + ") def\n")
            myfile.write("/centered_text_margin 165 2 div def\n")
            myfile.write("/text_width ticket_text stringwidth pop def\n")
            myfile.write("/half_text_width text_width 2 div def\n")
            myfile.write("/final_position centered_text_margin half_text_width sub def\n")
            myfile.write("final_position 55 moveto ticket_text show\n")
            myfile.write("/Helvetica findfont 10 scalefont setfont\n")
            myfile.write("10 40 moveto (Size: " + TKTsize + ") show\n")
            myfile.write("100 40 moveto (Price: $" + TKTprice + ") show\n")
            myfile.write("showpage\n")
            myfile.write("%%EOF\n")

        subprocess.Popen("C:\\Program Files\\GPLGS\\gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile=\"%printer%DYMO LabelWriter 400\" -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH C:\\DOHR\\ticket.ps")

class ticket_printer(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):

    _svc_name_ = "TGPrintServer"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Web and print server (Ticket Generator)"
    _svc_description_ = "This service implements a CherryPy web server, receives ticket information and builds a corresponding ticket postscript file.  It then prints that file to a local printer via a Ghostscript subprocess call."

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)          

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        #exit(0)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)                    

    def SvcDoRun(self):

        import servicemanager      
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,(self._svc_name_, ''))

        #self.timeout = 640000    #640 seconds / 10 minutes (value is in milliseconds)
        self.timeout = 120000     #120 seconds / 2 minutes
        # This is how long the service will wait to run / refresh itself (see script below)

        while 1:
            cherrypy.tools.CORS = cherrypy.Tool('before_finalize', CORS)
            webapp = WebServer()
            cherrypy.quickstart(webapp, '/', conf)

def ctrlHandler(ctrlType):
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrlHandler, True)
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(ticket_printer)
```

Comment: Your syntax on popen is wrong. Pass in an array of values, i.e. popen(["foo.exe","arg1"]).

Comment: Actually Popen has an option to pass a string instead of an array of args.  Check the docs.  I would rather use a list of args, but I couldn't get the correct printer selected when I did - something about the way Popen parses the double quotes...

Comment: And no, using a list of args doesn't change anything - i just tried it.

Comment: FWIW, in Windows the single-string version is likely to be preferred, because that's what the native interface has.  It depends on the implementation, though; I have seen interpreters that parse the string into tokens before mashing them back together again. :-(

Comment: Two thoughts: if `Popen` doesn't invoke the command shell, the percent-sign environment-variable expansion won't work, so try removing it; and you might need to quote the path and name of the executable inside the string since it contains spaces.  If that doesn't resolve your problem, I suggest that you download `psexec` from the MS website and using it to run `gswin32c.exe` in order to determine whether the issue is in `gswin32c.exe` or in your code.

Comment: It seems I need to escape my backslashes... 

In other news: I was playing around with the service in services.msc.  When I check the 'Allow service to interact with desktop' box under the logon tab, the call goes through properly.  However, it comes up via Interactive Services Detection.  I am able to replicate this strangeness using psexec with the -i 0 flag (session 0).

It is starting to seem like a permissions thing with the service I created.  I had to use an Administrative console to install the service originally, so maybe Python services are somehow limited as a result?

Comment: If you can replicate the problem using `psinfo` then it has nothing to do with your service.  From the sounds of it, it just doesn't work in session zero.  Now that I've realized you're trying to print, that doesn't surprise me - I would hope that it is possible to print from session zero, but you're likely to have to implement it yourself because probably only the simpler parts of the relevant API(s) will work.  This may involve some trial and error.